# How to connect Firebase to a Node.JS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I initially developed an application without NodeJS. But then I connected Node.JS because I need to take all the collections in the database using listCollections(). Before connecting Node Firebase, I initialized it in the Firebase.js file. Now I have added Node.JS and made the firebase-admin connection as shown in the example. But when starting the server, the error is

> FirebaseAppError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services. How to properly connect Firebase?

server.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port: ${PORT}`));

db.listCollections()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((snaps) => {
      console.log(snaps["_queryOptions"].collectionId); // LIST OF ALL COLLECTIONS
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

firebase.js:

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "..",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "...",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var db = firebase.firestore();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have client-side code that uses the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK for web clients, and then you have server-side code where you use the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js.

Since these pieces of code run completely separate from each other, uou'll need to initialize each SDK separately. And while you correctly initialize the client-side SDK, you're not initializing the Node.js SDK anywhere - so you'll need to add code for that. to learn how to do this, see the Firebase documentation on [initializing the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk).

Comment: Yes, I did everything as in the instructions, but I still have this error

Comment: The `server.js` code in your question doesn't show any call to `initializeApp`, which the linked documentation shows.